# Where filter with HasAndBelongsToMany relation in Loopback

Tags: loopback

first of all I am sorry if this has been asked 1st, I searched for this and got few links but wasn't helpful.

I am working on simple chat application created in Angular 4 which has Customer entity and Conversation entity and Message. In The customer => hasAndBelongsToMany => Conversation with MongoDb Connector.

In customer.json

```
"relations": {
  "conversations": {
    "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
    "model": "Conversation"
  }
}
```

In conversation.json

```
"relations": {
  "customers": {
    "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
    "model": "Customer"
  }
}
```

This creates table customerconversation which contains conversationId and customerId

Now basically I want to find conversation for two customer Ids, So I tried following filters but it doesn't seem to work and always returns empty array even though there is conversation having these two customer ids.

```
let filter = {
  where: {
    and: [
      {
        customers: {
          inq: [
            this.customerId // = 59bb981f35fcc941e8ba64e4
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        customers: {
          inq: [
            this.authService.getCurrentId() // = 59bb98c735fcc941e8ba68ff
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

and another without and operator

```
let filter = {
  where: {
    customers: {
      inq: [
        this.customerId,  // 59bb981f35fcc941e8ba64e4
        this.authService.getCurrentId() //  59bb98c735fcc941e8ba68ff
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

These both returns customer with mentioned Id but with 0 conversations. I know I can get all conversations of specific customer by using include filter for conversations but still those would need to be filtered as I want single conversation of this customer with another specific customer.

Comment: I don't see any relationship between these snippets and angular. Please use appropriate tag so your question will be directed to the right group of folks.

Comment: The code of filter is written in Angular application, still removed angular tag

Comment: it's written as JSON object to represent some data, and with no knowledge of the back-end (which I believe is MongoDb-related), one cannot turn that data into useful information. I'm fairly confident with my Angular skill but have no clue what's going on here, thus I think it's not related to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information by grabbing the customer first and then using the relations and include to get the data you need.

Example is based on the assumption that you are writing this using typescript & loopback-sdk-builder on an angular application.

```
this.customerApi
  .getConversations(this.authService.getCurrentId(), {
      where: {
      customerId: this.customerId
  })
  .subscribe(result => {
    // your logic here

  })
```